# Writing strings to CSV causing issue where the string in CSV is separated by commas (Python)

Tags: python, string, csv, file-writing

I am facing an issue that I was not able to resolve so far. I need to save a list of strings into the CSV file. I am able to do it however the strings from each element of the list are separated by commas. Why is that and what do I need to do to resolve this issue? Sorry for maybe simple question I am new to programming. I know it has to be somehow related to the string properties where each number is similar to an item in the list and is indexed however I was not able to find the cause of this behavior and how to resolve it.

Here is the code:

```
duplicity = ['8110278643', '8110278830', '8110283186']

with open("duplicty.csv", "w", newline="") as duplicity_csv:
    output_writer = csv.writer(duplicity_csv)
    header = ["Number"]
    output_writer.writerow(header)
    for item in duplicity:
        output_writer.writerow(item)
```

The output of this code in CSV is following:

```
Number
8,1,1,0,2,7,8,6,4,3
8,1,1,0,2,7,8,8,3,0
8,1,1,0,2,8,3,1,8,6
```

The expected output should be:

```
Number
8110278643
8110278830
8110283186
```

Thanks a lot for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`writerow` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) takes an **iterable** of strings. Each `item` in your list is in fact an iterable -- namely a string. Each element from that iterable (in your case each **letter** in the string) is taken as its own element in a sperate column.

You could just do this instead:

```py
...
    for item in duplicity:
        output_writer.writerow([item])
```

Comment: perfect thanks a lot it's working! so if i put the item of the list into a variable and use [], the whole payload of the variable is considered as 1 element?

Comment: @Samurajx Yes, in your case each `item` is a string. So if you enclose it in `[]`, you now have a list (an iterable) of strings of length 1. The `item` string is then considered one element. I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

`writerow()` needs list with items (even when you have single item in row) but you use `single string` and it treads it as `list of chars`

You need

```
output_writer.writerow( [item] )
```

Comment: No, it doesn't need a list. Any iterable works. Also `char` is not a thing in Python. The single string is an iterable of strings.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg frankly, it is not important details to solve problem. And `list of chars` can be more readable for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows), for example:

```
duplicity = ['8110278643', '8110278830', '8110283186']

with open("duplicty.csv", "w", newline="") as duplicity_csv:
    output_writer = csv.writer(duplicity_csv)
    header = ["Number"]
    output_writer.writerows([row] for row in header + duplicity)
```